# Non-image Data Classification by Convolutional Neural Network

Tags: python, conv-neural-network

I have a dataset where attributes are numerical and also there are multiple class. I want to classify them using CNN in Python. Is it possible ? After a lot of searching in google, I did not find anything related to non-image data . All classification examples of CNN are done in images. Please give me a clue. Thanks.

Comment: Defiantly is possible. Just choose some input dimensions and fill each feature with your values. If not enough values just fill the rest with ie 
zeroes.

Is there any reason why you need it to be CNN though?

CNN is useful when the data is dimensionally related. ie image where order of pixels is what determines the contents of image.

As far as I know there is no benefit to CNN if your data is independent.

Am still novice though, might have it wrong.

Comment: What exactly is your data?